# How to auto trigger Jenkins job/build when the changes are pushed to Github

Tags: windows, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, webhooks

I am using `Jenkins` in my local machine(Jenkins URL Not exposed over internet but internet is enabled on that machine.)

I did the following configuration changes:

1. Installed Git and Github plugins on Jenkins tool.
2. I have followed below steps for triggering auto build when the changes are made on Github. Configured Maven build and I am able to build manually by clicking `Build Now` link.
3. Configured Github section in Jenkins as follows (`Manage Jenkins` -> `Configure Systems`)
   [image: github services configuration in Jenkins]
4. I have created SSH keys using Git-bash and added Key in Github account (`settings` -> `SSH and GPG keys` -> `New SSh Key`)
   [image: SSH keys added in Git]
5. Configured Webhook settings in github repository. (`Repository` -> `Settings` -> `Webhook` -> `add webhook`) 
   [image: Webhook settings]
6. I am able to build manually but triggering build from github push event is not working. Giving the following warning:
   [image]

Kindly help me if there are any other solution are available.

Comment: Without Using WebHook you can get that process but minimum time required to check is 1 min.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar : can you please give me some reference link for that? or can you please list out the steps?

Comment: Registering webhooks for private repositories fails, however it is successful for public repositories using the same access token

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `git hooks`.

First make sure that you have enabled `Poll SCM` in your job. If you haven't enable it but do not provide any schedule.

Inside your Git repository there will be the hidden `.git` folder. Inside it you can find a sub-folder called `hooks`.

Now inside this folder create a file called `post-commit`and do not use any extension for the file and add the following lines to it and save it:

`#!/bin/bash
curl http://localhost:8080/git/notifyCommit?url=<GIT_REPO_URL>`

This will scan all the jobs that is using the `GIT_REPO` and trigger a build if there is  a change in your repository. For more details read this [document.](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-Pushnotificationfromrepository)

Comment: I guess, this is for local git repository. What if I want to build the trigger when I am changing data in global git repo(ex: https://github.com/HarshaBiyani)?

Comment: This is not for local git repository. This is for a remote repository.

Comment: Ok.. Can you please tell me .git folder path is from my machine or from github repository?

Comment: How am I supposed to know where do you have your `.git` folder in your machine? It must be in the directory where you have performed `git init` or where you have done a `clone` operation.